# How to know when the Collatz conjecture has been proved?

Tags: solution-verification, fake-proofs, collatz-conjecture

When using google to find out about research results about the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), I find numerous proofs by various people who seem to be experts of the topic and an abundance of proofs by amateurs. Here are 3 examples of such proofs, where at least the first two appear to be scientists with experience in relevant fields:

- [Complete Proof of the Collatz Conjecture, Farzali Izadi](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.06107) ([maybe this is Farzali Izadi's linkedin profile](https://ca.linkedin.com/in/farzali-izadi-95348619))
- [Solution to Collatz's Conjecture, Jose William Porras](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325389892_Solution_to_Collatz%27s_Conjecture)
- [The Visual Pattern in the Collatz Conjecture and Proof of No Non-Trivial Cycles, Fabian S. Reid](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.07955.pdf)

Wikipedia states that the conjecture is not proved, while for example Porras' proof is from 2018. I'm sure this proof has been checked and either considered correct or incorrect/incomplete, but I couldn't find anything substantial about checks of these proofs.

How to know what the current status is about the research here? Do I have to check all of those proofs on my own to know if one of them is correct?

Comment: An accepted proof will become very famous very quickly.  It is, of course, possible that one of the huge number of claimed proofs is correct...nobody could possibly keep up with the stack of these, though you are welcome to try.  Note that any proof writer is free to submit their paper to a peer-reviewed journal, though it is certainly difficult to get anyone to focus on Collatz arguments (just as, in the past, nobody wanted to look at the huge piles of Fermat "proofs").

Comment: If it has been published in a journal it means it went through a professional review. So, check if these "proofs" have been publish outside authors personal web pages.

Comment: *I couldn't find anything substantial about checks of these proofs* -- There are many red flags one can look for, this being one of them. Others are whether (and how) the author's proof is discussed on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and in some of the well known math blogs, as no mention there (or [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/)) is telling. Also, look at the author's publications in [MR](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) and [Zbl](https://zbmath.org/). Regarding someone unknown solving the problem, such a situation would generate more publicity than an expert solving it.

Comment: Proofs are checked very carefully ! However it is impossible to check all attempts since there are just too many. But chances that anyone has solved this already are virtually $0$ , and I have great doubts that anyone will be able to do it in the next $50$ years.

Comment: The Collatz conjecture has moreover a property that most conjectures like Goldbach or Riemann do not have. If there is a diverging trajectory , we might not be able to prove that within ZFC. It is not clear how we should decide in general whether a given sequence eventually terminates. Does anyone know "how sure" we can be that there is no diverging trajectory ?

Comment: @Peter If you understand this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562 then you probably will know and get the idea. I don't know what almost means in analytic math. I just see the term being used.

Comment: Don't worry. If anyone actually settles Collatz, there will be front page headlines in the New York Times. Everyone will know about it.

Comment: If I believed I had a proof, I’d offer a $10,000 reward for the first person who publishes a fault that I cannot fix within 30 days. So it would be reviewed.